# Prevent "Widget build" function in flutter from recalling

Tags: flutter, dart

I am pretty new in flutter, i have some scenario, i need to show some number of circles on screen and countdown timer of 5 seconds also, but the problem is that when i call function from controller to start timer "TimerState.StateTimerStart()", it also recalls the "widget builder" function of view and recreates the circles on new position.

My Controller:

```
  // Initial Count Timer value

  var SCount = 10;

  //object for Timer Class
  late Timer _timer;
  // a Method to start the Count Down
  void StateTimerStart(){
    //Timer Loop will execute every 1 second, until it reach 0
    // once counter value become 0, we store the timer using _timer.cancel()

    _timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), (timer) {
      if(SCount > 0){
        SCount--;
        update();
      }else{
        _timer.cancel();
      }
    });
  }
  // user can set count down seconds, from TextField
  void setnumber(var num){
    SCount = int.parse(num);
    update();
  }
  // pause the timer
  void Pause(){
    _timer.cancel();
    update();
  }
  // reset count value to 10
  void reset(){
    _timer.cancel();
    SCount = 10 ;
    update();
  }
}
```

My View:

```
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_circle_quiz/controller/CountDownTimer.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';

import 'circle_painter.dart';

class circle_screen extends StatelessWidget {
  Random random = new Random();
  final CountDownTimer TimerState = Get.put(CountDownTimer());

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;

    TimerState.StateTimerStart(); // HERE I AM CALLING MY FUNCTION FROM CONTROLLER
    
    int no_of_circles = random.nextInt(5) + 1;
    final children = <Widget>[];

    int prev_radius = 0;
    int prev_random_height = 0;
    int prev_random_width = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < no_of_circles; i++) {
      int radius = random.nextInt(60) + 10;
      int random_height = (random.nextInt(height.toInt()) + 60) - (radius * 2);
      int random_width = (random.nextInt(width.toInt()) + 60) - (radius * 2);
      children.add(Circle(center: {
        "x": random_width.toDouble() + (prev_radius * 2),
        "y": random_height.toDouble() + (prev_radius * 2)
      }, radius: radius.toDouble()));
      prev_radius = radius;
      prev_random_height = random_height;
      prev_random_width = random_width;
      
    }

    children.add(GetBuilder<CountDownTimer>(
        builder: (_) => Text('${TimerState.SCount}')));
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
          child: Center(
            child: Stack(
                // mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                // crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: children),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

If anyone willing to help will be really appreciated , Thanks!

Comment: do you only want to create the circles once when the widget is first created? Why not call the function on `initState`??

Comment: dear @h8moss, initstate also doing the same thing.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Never call MediaQuery.of(context) if not inside your widget tree, it can cause rebuild when the rotation of the screen. And use WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) { }) into your initState(){}. You can access the context.